# Creating Entity Relationship Diagram

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created the ERD of my system and now I would like to create a SQL Code.

[image: That's one of the table from my ERD]

So should a SQL Code look like this?:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    StudentID    INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName    VARCHAR(255),
    LastName     VARCHAR(255),
    ADDRESS      VARCHAR(255),
    PhoneNumber  VARCHAR(255),
    Email        VARCHAR(255),
    GroupID      INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY
);
```

Comment: that's the error msg:
`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with the code

Comment: in SQL `;` in the end is optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the `FOREIGN KEY` part of your query, you are not defining the foreign key there. If you now remove that, your query will work, but without a defined FK:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    StudentID    INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName    VARCHAR(255),
    LastName     VARCHAR(255),
    ADDRESS      VARCHAR(255),
    PhoneNumber  VARCHAR(255),
    Email        VARCHAR(255),
    GroupID      INT NOT NULL 
);
```

If you want to create the foreign key, you need to do something like this (with the correct table and column):

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    StudentID    INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName    VARCHAR(255),
    LastName     VARCHAR(255),
    ADDRESS      VARCHAR(255),
    PhoneNumber  VARCHAR(255),
    Email        VARCHAR(255),
    GroupID      INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Group(Group_ID)
);
```

Comment: how should I define `FOREIGN KEY`?

Comment: @Mateusz Take a shot with the second query on my answer, using the actual table and column

Answer (score 2):

Your "FOREIGN KEY" declaration is incomplete - you need to say which table/column the foreign key references.

If you just want to get the table built,

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    StudentID    INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName    VARCHAR(255),
    LastName     VARCHAR(255),
    ADDRESS      VARCHAR(255),
    PhoneNumber  VARCHAR(255),
    Email        VARCHAR(255),
    GroupID      INT NOT NULL);
```

should work.

Comment: I know that `FOREIGN KEY` constraints are defined almost identically across DBMS, but your link points to MySQL documentation and the question is tagged with SQL-Server (and there are actual differences in syntax which may matter.)

Comment: D'oh - you're right. Answered in haste - have removed the link!